# What is the best way to provide files for download from an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, paramiko

So I am supposed to create an application that uploads files(images) to an AWS Ec2 instance running Linux. I used Flask to create the upload logic and a simple HTML webpage to upload files.

After this I am supposed to generate a thumbnails and web optimized images from these images and store them on a directory and then provide the "web-optimized" image directory for download. How do I achieve this?

I have asked this previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60922885/how-do-i-provide-a-zip-file-for-download-from-an-aws-ec2-instance-running-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment107785266_60922885). I have pasted the code that I am using on that thread as well.

So my questions are :

1. Is it a good idea to use pscp to transfer files to the EC2 instance?
2. Is it a good idea to use paramiko to run a ssh on the remote instance in order to invoke a shell script that does the image processing (thumbnail web-optimized image generation using python)?
3. How do I get the compressed images via a simple download button on the client/host computer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is one of the limitations that you have to use EC2 instance only. If not I would recommend something like the following if you have to write a robust solution.

- Upload the file to an AWS S3 bucket, would be much cheaper to hold all the images (original). Let us call this `images_original`
- Now you can write a lambda to monitor the bucket, every time a new upload happens, process the image to create thumbnails etc for different resolutions, and upload them to their individual buckets (images_thumbnails, images_640_480 etc).
  To transform the images, I don't think you should be doing SSH into a remote instance to run the transform. Its better to use a python native library, such as  [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) inside the lambda itself.

On the client, you can simply access the respective file in the bucket. Eg if you want a thumbnail, you can access the thumbnail_bucket_url/file_name.jpeg etc.

Additionally, you can have a service that gets signed urls from S3.

To learn how to monitor an S3 bucket using a lambda you can refer [THIS](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aws_lambda/aws_lambda_using_lambda_function_with_amazon_s3.htm)

One important thing to remember while creating the lambda, all the depending libraries will have to be uploaded as a zipfile.

eg. `pip install Pillow -t`

Comment: We want to make the application open source. Initially we did use S3 and Lambda, but that means that a user would be stuck on the AWS platform.